# Do we need Microsoft.Web.MVC, I using ASP.NET MVC 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have upgraded my solution from VS2008. In our web project there are 2 references to ASP.NET MVC, the Microsoft.Web.MVC and System.Web.MVC. When I try removing the Microsoft.Web.MVC dll from the project and remove it from the web.config. After I do that I get compiler errors? I thought the System.Web.MVC has all the same functionality as the Microsoft.Web.MVC?

Comment: Found the out the Microsoft.Web.Mvc has the generic type safe Html.BeginForm<ClientController> methods. Our site is using them in a few places. I changed it back. All works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft.Web.MVC has all the MVC Futures, i.e. functionalitites that could be said "not on final release".

Answer (score 1):

Although the functionality you require is probably in ASP.NET MVC 2.0, the namespace of the types will have changed from `Microsoft.Web.MVC.whatever` to `System.Web.MVC.whatever`.

I am guessing the compile errors you are getting are related to this. Try searching your code for usages of types starting with "Microsoft.Web.MVC" and changing them. Does this get your application compiling?

If not, post a few examples of the compile errors onto your question.